# PostgreSQL Sequential scan (same table, same data returned, same shared buffers hit) 8x the time

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I was solving a problem why the same query in function took longer when executed via
`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE text_query;` (8s)
compare to
`RETURN QUERY select ...` (5s)

To my understanding it is because execute does not optimize.

So I compared explain analyze and found the problem. It was in one sequential scan where postgres optimized where condition. But the difference in time was way too big. So I separated it to the new query and it really was that different.

One select took 0.5s and second 4.2s, **both returning exactly the same data**. With such a difference I would expect that one were using index scan but it did not, both Sequential scan, I know that condition in where have also some cost but I never expected to have 8x the impact especially if I look at cost of the query it says  60434 compare to 87472. Not even close to 8x. (I ran it 10 times with same results)

**Optimized where condition**

```
select *
from table s_1
where
((stav >= 91) AND 
(date_trunc('week'::text, zacatek) >= '2018-07-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
AND (date_trunc('week'::text, zacatek) <= '2018-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

```
Seq Scan on table s_1  (cost=0.00..60434.66 rows=5260 width=115) (actual time=0.112..555.299 rows=96725 loops=1)
  Filter: ((s_1.stav >= 91) AND (date_trunc('week'::text, s_1.zacatek) >= '2018-07-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_trunc('week'::text, s_1.zacatek) <= '2018-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1255171
  Buffers: shared hit=30017
Planning Time: 0.073 ms
Execution Time: 559.906 ms
```

Explain Analyze: https://explain.depesz.com/s/o7Gm

**Non optimized where condition**

```
select *
from table s_1
where
((stav >= 91) AND 
(date_trunc('week'::text, zacatek) <= date_trunc('week'::text, date_trunc('week'::text, to_timestamp('2019-01-06 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'::text)))) 
AND (date_trunc('week'::text, zacatek) >= date_trunc('week'::text, ((date_trunc('week'::text, to_timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'::text)) - '5 mons'::interval) + '1 day'::interval))))
```

```
Seq Scan on table s_1  (cost=0.00..87472.58 rows=5260 width=115) (actual time=0.958..4235.196 rows=96725 loops=1)
  Filter: ((s_1.stav >= 91) AND (date_trunc('week'::text, s_1.zacatek) <= date_trunc('week'::text, date_trunc('week'::text, to_timestamp('2019-01-06 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'::text)))) AND (date_trunc('week'::text, s_1.zacatek) >= date_trunc('week'::text, ((date_trunc('week'::text, to_timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'::text)) - '5 mons'::interval) + '1 day'::interval))))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1255171
  Buffers: shared hit=30017
Planning Time: 0.166 ms
Execution Time: 4241.479 ms
```

Explain Analyze: https://explain.depesz.com/s/5Rkv

**My question is:** why is there such a big difference without any obvious reasons, method is the same, number of returned rows is the same and expected cost is also rather similar.

> PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Comment: Try to repeat the experiment and see if the result is persistent.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes I ran it more than 10 times with same results

Comment: This sounds as if the (in theory constant) expression in the WHERE clause is evaluated for every row - and the "non-optimized" one is way more expensive. If I had to guess: it has something to do with the fact that `date_trunc()` is marked as volatile